# validator method not working on change

Tags: magento2

```
<input name="mobile_number" id="mobilenumber" type="number" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?>" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true,mobile_ksa:true,maxlength:7}">

$.validator.addMethod('mobile_ksa', function (phone_number, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && 
    phone_number.match(/^(05)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
    }, $.mage.__('wrong phone number. example: 05xxxxxxxx'));
});
```

the above code I am using for validation is working when I click on the button but I want it to work when I type how can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use key up event.

Answer (score 0):

'Please check if you added `'mage/validation'` in `require` and `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` on the `<form>` tag yet.

Please refer:

template.phtml

```
<form class="form" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' ...anotherAttributes>
      <input name="mobile_number" id="mobilenumber" type="number" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?>" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true,mobile_ksa:true,maxlength:7}">
</form>

<script>
      require([
            'jquery',
            'mage/validation'
      ], function($) {
            $.validator.addMethod('mobile_ksa', function (phone_number, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
                    phone_number.match(/^(05)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
            }, $.mage.__('wrong phone number. example: 05xxxxxxxx'));
            
            //Validate on keydown event
            $('#mobilenumber').on('keydown', function () {
                $.validator.validateSingleElement($(this), {})
            })
      })
      
</script>
```

Comment: Your code has some mistake. $('#mobilenumber') using jQuery but didn't require jQuery. 
data-mage-init registered the validator, you are requiring extra validate. The question is how to validate a field once customer typing please focus to this point.

Comment: Hi @HoangHieu, thank you. my mistake was when I  put the code outside`require` block. But the 'mage/validation' is still required if you want to add a new validation method. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Your code is correct.